# Spring JPA updating Entity while selecting data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring + JPA + Hibernate in my project, I have a method annotated with @Transactional.
I am performing few save operation using JPA Repository and in between I am querying some data. When logic reaches JPA read data logic it starts executing bunch of update statements.
Logic works perfectly fine if I remove Transactional annotation.

I don;t want update query to be executed if I am updating entities, it should be called only when JPARepository save method is called or when transaction is completed.
Is there any configuration that can be added ?

Comment: So, where is the question in this question?

Comment: Just updated my questions.

Comment: What do you mean &#39; query executed&#39; ?yoo see in console / log files then it&#39;s normal ? What query do you see? Can you show your mapping , queries and action that you do. If you modify x-to-many it&#39;s produces modify query. But real execution happens onle in commit or flush

Comment: Seems like jpa is commiting pending updates before performing select statement.

Comment: did you find a solution for that problem? I am facing the same issue